# How to solve "ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0" using ngx-translate in ionic 3?

Tags: json, html, typescript, ionic3, angular5

I am getting above error, while using ngx-translate to change language 
    in ionic 3.

[image]

My Code is:
   1. I have installed

```
**npm install @ngx-translate/core @ngx-translate/http-loader --save**
```

2. then I have imported below 3 in app.module.ts:

To use ngx-translate, it must first be imported and added to the 
   imports array in the NgModule of the application. Here’s an example 
   of how to do this:

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
```

3.then export function:

```
  export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
   return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
  }
```

4.then import module in @ngModule

```
 @NgModule({
   declarations: [
    MyApp,
    MainPage,
    SearchPipe,
    // SortPipe
   ],
   imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
     loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
      deps: [Http]
    }
  }),
 ]
})
```

5.then import TranslateService in app.component.ts file:

```
import { TranslateService, LangChangeEvent } from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

and have put

```
this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
  console.log("onLangChange", event.translations)
})
this.translate.onDefaultLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) 
 => {
  console.log("onDefaultLangChange", event.translations)
})
```

in constructor

```
6. then in home.ts

 import { TranslateService, LangChangeEvent } from '@ngx- translate/core';
```

in constructor :

```
  translate.setDefaultLang('en');
```

outer constructor :

```
  public changeLanguage(language)
  {
    console.log("language", language);
    this.translate.use(language);
  }
```

7.In home.html

```
   <ion-title>{{ 'title' | translate }}</ion-title>
   <div *ngIf="forUserContent"></div>
   <div *ngIf="forSupplierContent">
   <button ion-button full class="review-btn"(click)="showreviewlist()">{{ 'review' | translate }}</button>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="forBothContent">
   <button ion-button full class="review-btn" (click)="showreviewlist()">{{ 'review' | translate }}</button>
   </div>

   <button ion-button (click)="changeLanguage('de')">{{ 'german' | translate }}</button>
   <button ion-button (click)="changeLanguage('en')">{{ 'english' | translate }}</button>
```

8.In home.module.ts:

```
 import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
 import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
 import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

 export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
 }

 @NgModule({
   declarations: [
    HomeappPage,
   ],
   imports: [
     IonicPageModule.forChild(HomeappPage),
     HeaderComponentModule,
     FooterComponentModule,
     TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
       provide: TranslateLoader,
       useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
       deps: [Http]
     }
   })
  ],
  exports: [
   HomeappPage,
   TranslateModule
  ]
})
```

9.created two json file with specific language:
       store data of language in .json file.

1.en.json

```
   {
     "title": "HOME",
     "german": "German",
     "english": "English",
     "review": "Review List"
   }
```

2.de.json

```
    {
     "title": "ZUHAUSE",
     "german": "Deutsch",
     "english": "Englisch",
     "review": "Überprüfungsliste",
    }
```

I want solution and get strings from specific json file, when i change 
    the language in application

Comment: The unexpected token error is usually for improperly formatted json. The only thing that stands out at me is your use of the Umulaut. Have you tested without an Umulaut?

Comment: Your de.json has a `,` at the end of the last item...https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=ff35715a7b1240049e73cd1610fc2b55

Comment: @Jags that is not the issue. those characters can be read in utf-8

Comment: I removed **,** from de.json. still getting same error

Comment: can you please find out any solution to get strings in html with pipe | translate. your help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a demo project by

```
ionic start DemoProject super
```

Check the app.module.ts file. They are using HttpClient instead of Http. Mine is working with this config.

This is the config if your Angular version is 5.
You can get and install the proper `@ngx-translate/core`and `@ngx-translate/http-loader` version from here.
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core